# Apache Redirect Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, redirect

I am running Apache on CentOS 6.  I have something similar to the below example at the start of my Virtual Host section in httpd.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.org/freedom/
  Redirect / https:/myotherdomain.com/SomeOtherURL/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.org
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.org
  Redirect / https:/myotherdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that the first (more specific) redirect - for mydomain.org/freedom/ is ignored and that URL is just redirected as per the second more general rule for the same domain.

I have tried switching the order of the rules to no avail.

I have verified that the second redirect is happening via this service:

http://wheregoes.com/retracer.php

Any suggestions as to why this is not working?

Comment: `ServerName mydomain.org/freedom/` is not valid servername, servername has to be a servername !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server name is the host name not a path.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.org
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.org
  Redirect /freedom/ https:/myotherdomain.com/SomeOtherURL/
  Redirect / https:/myotherdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```